# index.html file not working when opening through folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

my project is working fine when I am opening it through vs code live server , it has API in it [image]

but when I am opening it directly through my folder its doesn't work , I don't understand what's the problem . Also the URL changed , Please someone help me , what's the problem ?? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that in the first case, the page is being served by a web server, whereas in the second, you're just loading the file off of the disk, directly into the browser.

In the case of a static HTML page, this doesn't matter, because there isn't any processing that has to be done, but when you start using web services that get called by Javascript, it does matter, because those web services are programs that have to be run on the server side, and that server isn't available if you're just loading the files off of the disk.

Answer (score 0):

It depends about the structure of your HTML file, but if it calls a function it will be have to be computed somewhere and you need to validate that an engine actually runs it.

I am assuming you are using a standard procedure, make sure your executor is on.

Answer (score 0):

When you open an HTML file directly from your disk, some JavaScript functions might be restricted due to the browser's security policies. This happens because loading files locally is seen as a security risk. Using Live Server bypasses these restrictions by running a local server, creating a more real server-like environment, and allowing your JavaScript code to work smoothly.